# fetchedResultsController fetches empty data

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Coredata Fetching an Object from an unsaved Context, causing app crash. My iOS app is getting irregular behaviour when it comes to fetching some data and having unsaved changes. 
I have already used

```
[myFetchRequest setIncludesPendingChanges:YES];
```

but still no changes. Any solution?

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsController {

  if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
  }

 NSString *loginUser=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"currentUser"];

 AppDelegate *sharedDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [sharedDelegate managedObjectContext];
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
 [fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
 NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ThreadInfo"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
 [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

 NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                          initWithKey:@"threadDate" ascending:NO];
 [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];


 NSPredicate *threadPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userEmail == %@",loginUser];

 [fetchRequest setPredicate:threadPredicate];
 [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

 [fetchRequest setIncludesPendingChanges:YES];
 NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
 [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                               cacheName:nil];
 _fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
 _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

 return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

Comment: When you crash, what message do you get and what does your stack trace look like?

Comment: CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x6b8bf10 ' }  and debug the code and found that data is empty from fetch Result

Comment: Have you looked at the "Fault cannot be fulfilled" suggestion here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTroubleshooting.html